# Is faunadb realtime?

Tags: faunadb

Wondering if `faunadb` support realtime, which is a big thing `firebase` supports?

I noticed `faunadb` support `graphql` but without `subscription` supported.

Sorry if this question is naive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fauna doesn't as of Oct 2019 support streaming push updates. However, fauna does allow you to poll very cheaply the history of of documents, allowing for change feeds to be built. Streaming is being worked on and I imagine this answer will be edited in the not too distant future.

Comment: What's a year between friends? :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems Faunadb is actively adding real-time capabilities now([official announcement](https://fauna.com/blog/new-collaboration-authentication-real-time-streaming-capabilities#real-time-database-streaming)).

Comment: Note that StackOverflow does not consider externally linked content as part of an answer. So your answer shrinks to "Things are changing now.", which might only be considered as an answer with generous flexibility. Please consider summarising the announcement and maybe making more obvious that it is from "the source". (Hmm, okay, "official" goes a long way towards that last part, I admit.)